# What exactly does the `LocalImp` parameter do in randomForests package?

Tags: r, random-forest

Can anyone explain, in relatively simple English, what the parameter `localImp` does in the `randomForest` package?

The `randomForest` documentation describes this parameter as:

> should casewise importance measure be computed? (Setting this to TRUE
>   will override importance.)

It also states that it produces:

> a p by n matrix containing the casewise importance measures, the [i,j]
>   element of which is the importance of i-th variable on the j-th case.
>   NULL if localImp=FALSE

Can someone explain exactly what this means or point me in the direction of a paper where they discuss this parameter in detail.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The randomForest package is more or less a wrapper for fortran code written by Leo Breiman and Adel Cutler. Breiman was a statistics professor at UC Berkeley and they have preserved his website after his passing.

It is an amazing resource:
https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/

In this site, they mention the following on the classification page:

> For each case, consider all the trees for which it is oob. Subtract the percentage of votes for the correct class in the variable-m-permuted oob data from the percentage of votes for the correct class in the untouched oob data. This is the local importance score for variable m for this case.

So, for observation i, take all of the trees that did not train on i because it was not selected in the bootstrap. Now, consider variable m. Permute the values of m for the left out (oob) observations of every tree not containing i. Calculate the average out-of-bag accuracy across these trees. Also calculate the out-of-bag accuracy for these trees without permuting the values of variable m. Subtracting the average of the permuted m accuracy from the non-permuted oob accuracy gives the (i,m) local importance measure.

Answer (score 2):

Localimp (local importance) sets the importance of each variable in the classification of specific individuals (localImp=TRUE) this way you can see how much each feature influenced the output of each single row.

You can read : 
[Understanding variable importances in forests of randomized trees](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4928-understanding-variable-importances-in-forests-of-randomized-trees.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjP34_L2vjjAhUyQkEAHaYHDJQQFjAPegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw1LhlfMtPTKwPe0X5QiNyWj&cshid=1565454116207)

also
[Random forest guide](http://paolaelefante.com/2016/03/a-small-guide-to-random-forest-part-2/)