# How to obtain feature importance by class using ranger?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I have been using ranger and randomForest functions in R. I am particularly interested in getting the importance of features (predictors) for each class that I am trying to predict, rather than the overall importance for all classes together. I know how to do this using the importance() function from randomForest in which it seems to be the default behaviour:

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(100)
rfmodel <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data = iris, ntree = 1000, importance = TRUE)
importance(rfmodel)
```

This results in a matrix with the importance of each feature for each of the three classes

Alternatively for ranger I am running:

```
library(ranger)
rangermodel<-ranger(Species ~ ., data = iris, num.trees = 1000, write.forest=TRUE, importance="permutation", local.importance=TRUE)
importance(rangermodel)
rangermodel$variable.importance
rangermodel$variable.importance.local
```

rangermodel$variable.importance provides the importance of the features for the whole classification problem, but not by class. While rangermodel$variable.importance.local provides the importance for each case, but also not by class.

The ranger documentation does not seem to provide information on this.
The only question I could find on the topic is this one: [How can I separate the overall variable importance values when using Random forest?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_separate_the_overall_variable_importance_values_when_using_Random_forest) But they did not reach a conclusion on how to achieve this with ranger.
Changing the ranger code as below did not provide the output I am looking for either:

```
rangermodel<-ranger(Species ~ ., data = iris, num.trees = 1000, write.forest=TRUE, importance="impurity")
```

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to use local variable importance, defined as below:

> For each case, consider all the trees for which it is oob. Subtract the percentage of votes for the correct class in the variable-m-permuted oob data from the percentage of votes for the correct class in the untouched oob data. This is the local importance score for variable m for this case.
> [Source: Breiman's and Cutler website, section: Variable Importance](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm)

Extracting local variable importance from `ranger`: you need to specify *both* `importance = "permutation"` *and* `local.importance = TRUE`

```
library(ranger)
rf.iris <- ranger(Species ~ ., iris, importance = "permutation", 
             local.importance = TRUE)
rf.iris$variable.importance.local
```

Then you can

```
library(data.table)    
as.data.table(rf.iris$variable.importance.local)[,Species := iris$Species][,lapply(.SD,mean),by=Species]

Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1:     setosa      0.01316     0.00252      0.11192     0.12548
2: versicolor      0.00800     0.00120      0.10672     0.11112
3:  virginica      0.01352     0.00316      0.10632     0.09956
```

Refs:

- [SO: What exactly does the `LocalImp` parameter do in randomForests package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443766/what-exactly-does-the-localimp-parameter-do-in-randomforests-package)
- [R::ranger github issue: variable importance by class #552](https://github.com/imbs-hl/ranger/issues/552)