# R randomForest localImp for test set

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm using the R-package randomForest version 4.6-14. The function `randomForest` takes a parameter `localImp` and if that parameter is set to true the function computes local explanations for the predictions. However, these explanations are for the provided training set. I want to fit a random forest model on a training set and use that model to compute local explanations for a separate test set. As far as I can tell the `predict.randomForest` function in the same package provides no such functionality. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain more about what it means to have some local explanation on a test set?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443766/what-exactly-does-the-localimp-parameter-do-in-randomforests-package) along with the [package document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf), the variable importance (or, the casewise importance implied by `localImp`) evaluates how the variable may affect the prediction accuracy. On the other hand, for the test set where there is no label to assess the prediction accuracy, the variable importance should be unavailable.

Comment: Local explanations of a test set would be something similar to Shapley values ideally, i.e., for each observation the sum of the contributions of all variables would sum to the prediction. For linear regression the explanations would be the coefficients times the observations. 

I'm not perfectly sure how the algorithm works, but to me it seemed like an obvious thing that the explanations should be evaluated on a test set, so I assumed this was possible until I actually tried.

Your link to an answer links to this thread for me, could you try to fix it?

Comment: @user2882096  have just edited it. I am not familiar with the local explanations or Shapley values, but I feel that the casewise variable importance (`localImp`) in the `randomForest` package may not be what you want.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the link! I had read that answer, and I don't see any reason why that algorithm couldn't be used for a test set. The only difference would be that the trees are already constructed when the algorithm is run.

Comment: @user2882096 I just found out that your test set is more of a validation set, therefore the labels exist. Sorry for my misunderstanding when writing the answer. The permutation-based variable importance should be available for a validation set. However, the casewise variable importance is still undefined. The same referred answer pointed out that the algorithm considers out-of-bag samples. In the validation set, every observation is new, and the concept of OOB is not valid.

Comment: Hmm you're right, the OOB information is only relevant in the fitting of the model. I might think about implementing something similar for a separate test set. Thank you for the help!